# Terminate a map loop in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm attempting to break out of a loop, once I have found what I'm looking for, in this case a quote.

I know from using things like Java that it is in fact possible, however it is proving more difficult than I thought in RN. When I use a JS break, it simply says its a syntax error, is there any `break` statements in RN?

[image]

```
quotes.quotesArray.map((quote, i) => {
    if(!quote.isRead){
        return <Text key={i} style={styles.container, styles.quote}>{quotes.quotesArray[i].quotation}</Text>;                    
        break;
    } else {
       return 
    }
})
```

Comment: `break` is not avaiable in `map` loop, for that cases use `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to prematurely break the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It looks like you want to render the first element matching the `!quote.isRead` predicate. If that is the case you can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first unread quote and then render it if it exists.

```
var unreadQuote = quotes.quotesArray.find(quote => !quote.isRead)
render() {
  return (
    unreadQuote && 
    <Text style={styles.container, styles.quote}>{unreadQuote.quotation}</Text>;
  )
}
```

Comment: Mercuy It says that the break is an "Unsyntactic Break" - Does it mean there is a break statement that will work in React Native? Just curious

Comment: The `break` statement in React Native is identical to the `break` statement as it is used in the browsers. It follows the same rules. Which means they are used in `while` and `for` loops and `switch` statements for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with filter and map and move the render of the component to a function:

```
renderQuote(quote, i) {
    return (
        <Text key={i} style={styles.container, styles.quote}>
            {quote.quotation}
        </Text>
    );
}

// On JSX

{ quotes.quotesArray.filter((quote) => !quote.isRead).map((quote, i) => this.renderQuote(quote, i) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're return starts the next loop so it never hits the `break`, here is another way you could set this up. Edited to for loop from forEach for break to be valid.

```
const quote = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < quotes.quotesArray.length; i++) {
  if (!quote.isRead[i]) {
    quote.push(<Text key={i} style={styles.container, styles.quote}>{quotes.quotesArray[i]}</Text>);
    break;
  }
}
```

You could also use lodash's .find() method to filter the array and return the first element that returns true in your callback and use that data for your text element.

Comment: `break;` cannot be used in that place.

Comment: @zerkms yeah totally forgot you cant break outta forEach, it would have to be set up as a regular 'for loop' for the break to work